# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to connect to my local database to select a sql database and print the column names but I keep getting this exception:

> > System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> >     instance of an object.'
>
> System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get
>   returned null.

Can somebody help me?

```
    string constr = 
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\NORTHWND.MDF;Integrated Security=True;"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
```

Comment: You already have your connection string in the form of `constr`. The configuration manager's connection string is meant for retrieving a ConnectionString setting from a config file by name. You're currently using the entirety of a connection string as the name for lookup.

Comment: The variable `constr` is your connection string.  You are using it as an index into the dictionary of connection strings that the `ConfigurationManager` maintains: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[constr]`.  Either use the connection string alone, or use the name of the string that you have in the config file

Comment: Ok I tried fixing it a little and it still has the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` then your connection string needs to be in your `web.config` in the `configuration/connectionStrings` section similar to this:

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
            <add name="db" connectionString="Data 
          Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
          Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\NORTHWND.MDF;Integrated Security=True;"/>
   </connectionStrings>
<configuration/>
```

You then access it by the value of the `name` attribute, like this:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: Yup I think that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing the SqlConnection a little goofy. 
Try this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
```

Comment: I have to use ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString because it's needed later on in the code. So you can understand better I'm trying to replicate the code from the GetData() method here: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-data-from-database-in-HTML-table-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: It's hard to see what the problem is without seeing the rest of the code but try using:
`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"]` instead of `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[constr]`

Comment: Ok I edited the code a little and it still has the same result